# Fast field extraction with grep

Tags: shell-script, grep, regular-expression

## The problem

I have a 32M lines file with the following format

```
token^Iname^Iurl$
```

where `^I` is the *tab* escape sequence, and `$` is the *end-of-line*.

I need to get the `url` corresponding to not more than 10k matches with the field `name`.
What I've done is

```
# Get second column
cut -f2 <myFile> |
# Find the word and line number
grep -nwi "<matchWord>" |
# Get just the number
cut -f1 -d ':' |
# Not more than 10k
head -n10000
```

And then, for each entry of the previous output

```
# Print line number 
sed -n '<number>{p;q}' <myFile>
# Get 3rd field
cut -f3
```

Now, this last operation with `sed` is ridiculously slow.
I am wondering how to get the all of this by using `grep` only, or any other way that doesn't slow down after the first 1k matches.

## Idea

It would be just perfect to be able to operate `grep` on the whole line (without `cut -f2`), targeting only the second column, and then `cut -f3`, but I don't have a clue of how to do it.

## Example

Line xyz

```
qwertyuiop^Ibananas are yellow^Ihttp://mignons.cool$
```

Match word *yellow* in field `name` -> give me `http://mignons.cool`.

`cut` is needed, because I don't want to match stuff in the field `token` and `url`.

If I send to `grep` a `cut` of `myFile`, then I no longer have access to the `url` field, which I am interested in.

## Input and expected output

Input file:

```
mxp4EdOy-IXkuwsuOfs0EQ^Ilegal yellow pad paper^I0/3/3031.jpg$
AeS7tgmlVffBhousr9YY5Q^Ihelicopter parking only sign^I0/3/3032.jpg$
8dl-VixSjG4Y0FpX9f5KHA^Iwritten list ^I0/3/3033.jpg$
XYvKZC3D_JSwlY8SPl-zLQ^Ihelicopter parking only road sign^I0/3/3034.jpg$
xF6zpvpHcmfpHP2MmT2FVg^Irun menu windows programming^I0/3/3035.jpg$
mCJvV2rXOmItLBkMZlyIwQ^Icoffee mug^I0/3/3040.jpg$
ZiobHk_dLsN-Q921KPJUTA^Icarpet^I0/3/3197.jpg$
xFrbGOMfVMl0WeqVAcT27A^Iwater jugs^I0/3/3199.jpg$
```

where `^I` is the *tab* escape sequence, and `$` is the *end-of-line*.

Match word `helicopter`.

Expected output (not more than 10k lines):

```
0/3/3032.jpg
0/3/3034.jpg
```

## Potential solution

Since the `url` field contains only numbers, I could

```
cut -f 2,3 <myFile> | grep <matchWord> | cut -f2 | head -n10000
```

But it would be nicer to `grep` the second field only...

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do but I am pretty sure ```awk``` can do a better job, replacing your usage of ```cut``` and ```grep```.

Comment: I put an example at the end, @phk.

Comment: Took some time to figure out that `^I` is `<TAB>`. Nice job…

Comment: @Arthur2e5, I thought it was implicit (if you use `cat -A`, that's how they are marked). Anyhow, I've updated the question for ease of understanding. Tnx for the comment.

Comment: Give as an example a few lines from the input file and desired output.

Comment: @jimmij, question updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should not try to cut `cut` out. In fact, trying to consolidate a pipeline into a single process for the handling of 32M input lines will very likely negatively affect your task's overall completion time. This depends, though, on the kind of computer on which you run the job.

If the machine on which you process your data has multiple processor cores, then, generally speaking, consolidating a task loop to a single process means consolidating the whole job to a single processor core. This may be desirable on systems with only a single processor core, or else if overall CPU time is precious, but, in my experience, it is better to saturate a processor and use all cores concurrently to complete the task sooner.

That said, you definitely can `grep` just the second field:

```
grep -E $'\t(.* )?yellow( .*)?\t' <infile
```

...that pattern will match only strings which occur between two tab characters on a line, and will match only those strings which are bounded on both sides with either a space or one of the field delimiting tabs. With GNU `grep` you can also add the `-m`ax match switch for limiting output to no more than 10K matches. And so...

```
grep -m10000 -E $'\t(.* )?yellow( .*)?\t' <infile | cut -f3
```

...would be enough to do the whole job.

Comment: Sweet! I'm already saturating all cores by matching 5k different `<matchWord>` using multiple threads. What about the syntax you've used? Could you explain it a little more, perhaps? The use of parenthesis and `?` are a tad obscure.

Comment: @Atcold - do you have a specific question about it? its extended regexp is all, really.

Comment: The use of parenthesis and `?` are a tad obscure. Moreover, once I have the matches, I have to move files around (~500GB, overall), so the bottleneck becomes the disk access time...

Comment: @Atcold - well, the `(` parens `)` delimit a subexpression - which is basically just a way of gathering the two `' '` and `.*` expressions into a single expression so we can apply the `?` optional operator to it. basically it works out that the search phrase either matches immediately adjacent to a `\t`ab boundary on either side, *or* there is a an `?` optional intervening match for `.*` 0 or more of any character followed/preceded by a space. see? regarding your disk access time - if you broke the job up a little so you could read/write in tandem it would help. you can do that with `-m`.

Comment: Gotcha! You've optionalised the `_.*` and `.*_`! Sweet! One more thing. `yellow` sometimes is `man'` (can end with an apostrophe). So, I usually add an extra quotation set, like `"man'"`. Is it still valid with the `-E` argument?

Comment: @Atcold - not like that. If you want to be able to abut either an apostrophe or a space on the right side, you might do instead: `$'\t(.* )?yellow(['\'$' ].*)?\t'` so you use the `[` bracket expression `]` to match either an apostrophe or a space on the right. The `$'...'` dollar-sign hard-quotes are only necessary to expand the `\t` escape because it can be annoying to explain white-space in a web browser. you could use plain old quotes and drop the dollar sign if you just used actual tab characters in place of the `\t` escapes.

Comment: @Atcold - maybe try other char classes: `$'\t(.* )?["'\'$']?[yY]ellow[[:punct:]]?( .*)?\t'`

Comment: OK, it is becoming complicated. The 'problem' is that the matching word sometimes contain symbols as well (`m&ms`, `mcdonalds'`, `boys'`, `spider-man`, `at&t`), so I fixed this by matching the word with `" "`. The same way I create folders with the `" "`.

Comment: I think that for the moment I will stick on using `cut -f 2,3 <myFile> | grep -wi "<matchWord>" | cut -f2 | head -n10000`. But at least I've learnt something new today! Oh, and yes, in the file there are the actual tab characters, but I showed them here as `^I` for ease of visualisation.

Comment: Since you already know that you only need a limited amount of matches, and you also know that out of a 3-tuple string set you need the last tuple, most probably the fastest solution which is close to what you initially were after is: `grep -i -m 10000 -w 'helicopter' input | cut -d $'\t' -f3`. For a quick test I have created a 460MB file using your pattern above and run the following: `time grep -i -m 100000 -w 'helicopter' input | cut -d $'\t' -f3 | wc -l` (100000 since 10000 matches are too fast). It took 2.3s on my machine; the 10000 matches take roughly 200ms.

Comment: @Moreaki - that isn't the same - yours could match field 1,2,3. mine can only match field 2. also, i dont like `-w` and prefer to be explicit about that stuff. ditto for letter case, usually. how long did it take with my pattern anyway?

Comment: @mikeserv: Sure, which is why I didn't post it as an answer, however looking at the sample data, it does not look at all that this be the case. Then again, the difference in speed versus accuracy does not warrant my proposal to even be considered seriously. Your accurate solution takes 2.7s for the same test with 100000 matches and 280ms for 10000 matches.

Comment: @mikeserv, sorry for troubling you more, but how would you go for words that may contain symbols? I fear that the `-E` will try to use those symbols as operators, whereas the plain `grep` simply takes them as literals. Do I have to escape all of them with `[` brakets `]`? Right now the `"` quotations `"` were doing the job pretty well with vanilla `grep`. And, anyhow, the bottleneck were the `5` TB I was trying to copy. I'm going to *sim-link* them now and keep everything on 2 `1` TB SSDs and avoid duplicates.

Comment: @mikeserv, moreover I didn't quite get what you meant by "if you used the escape character or the actual tab". In the files there are *tabs*, but in order to show the type of white space I put here the output of `cat -A` for better readability. So, for what you said, there is no need of `$'...'`, correct?

Comment: @Atcold - you have to match the tabs. if you dont put literal tab characters in your pattern, then youve got to get them in there somehow otherwise. thats why i use `$'...'` here because its hard to screw up. but if you dont want to use it then youll need actual tabs chracters rather than the backslash esacape sequence `\t`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.  Easiest is probably with `awk`

```
$ awk -F$'\t' '$2 = /helicopter/ {print $3}' input.txt | head -n 10000
0/3/3032.jpg
0/3/3034.jpg
```

- `-F$'\t'` sets the field separator to TAB
- `$2 = /helicopter/` matches only on field 2
- `print $3` prints field 3 on matches

If you want case-insensitive full-word matches, try this:

```
awk -F$'\t' 'tolower($2) ~ /\<helicopter\>/ { print $3}' input.txt | head -n 10000
```

The `\<` and `\>` (word boundary markers) probably only work on `gawk` - which is standard if you're on Linux.  And note also that the comparison operator has changed from `=` to `~`.

Comment: **A-W-E-S-O-M-E-!-!-!**

Comment: Next thing in my todo list: read `man awk`.

Comment: the `awk` man page is a reference only, won't teach you how to use it.  search for `awk` on this site instead.  lots of good awk examples and explanations here.

Comment: With `grep` I specified `w`, i.e. match full word (not only parts). Moreover, I would also like it to be *case-insensitive*. Could you add this two things?

Comment: btw, not at all awesome...this is about as absurdly trivial an example of awk as you can get.

Comment: Actually, there is a bug. If I use the match word `park`, here it is finding me also `parking`. That's why I used `-w` in grep. Could you please fix it?

Comment: `$2 = /car/` matches also `carpet`, `caribou` and other stuff. `$2 = /\<car\>/` and `$2 = /"[^[:alpha:]]"car"[^[:alpha:]]"/` ([ref.](http://superuser.com/a/349119/224792)) don't work.

Comment: btw, that's not a bug.  that's an example of the beginnings of scope creep, where the specs repeatedly get changed until eventually the initial simple job becomes extremely complicated.

Comment: @Atcold, `$2 = /\<car\>/` works. just tested it.  that's what `\<` and `\>` are for.  GNU only.  `perl` and `pcre` uses `\b` instead,

Comment: I am on Ubuntu, and `/\<car\>/` finds nothing...

Comment: then you're probably running `mawk` or `original-awk` instead of `gawk`.  Try running `/bin/ls -lF /etc/alternatives/awk`.  Then `sudo apt-get install gawk gawk-doc pinfo` (pinfo is for reading the gawk docs) followed by `sudo update-alternatives --config awk`

Comment: `/etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/mawk*`

Comment: well. you know what you have to do.

Comment: `apt-get install gawk` I guess... Let me see if it works! :) Sweet, it replaced the default `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to also try locally setting `LC_ALL=C` in your environment.

If `LC_ALL` is a UTF8 locale, then that can imply that grep needs to do UTF8 decoding on the input stream before doing matching, and that can significantly slow down `grep`

Comment: This is more a comment that an answer, is it?

Comment: @Atcold OP had a performance problem with grep. This is one way to reduce performance problems with grep.

Comment: It's not a solution to every problem, but answers typically aren't, additionally, if some other person has related issues to yours, this answer might be all they needed.